# How can I remove this sliding door?

Tags: doors

I have a sliding glass door.  It sticks horribly.  The track is just filthy, so my assumption is the two sets of wheels on the bottom of the door are gunked up and need replaced.

I remove the top strip of trim that holds the door in place.  However, I can't get either wheel to raise or lower at all.  Neither screw will turn - completely locked up.  I've tried Liquid Wrench - no luck.

Even though the door is relatively low in the track, there is not enough clearance along the top jamb to tilt the door out.  It's effectively stuck!

Help!  Any idea on how I can get those wheels lowered even a bit to give me the clearance to remove the door?

Comment: [sledgehammer](http://www.google.com/url?source=imglanding&ct=img&q=http://www.quedat.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/sledgehammer.jpg&sa=X&ei=jbFoT-z1NtTE0AHw662fCQ&ved=0CA0Q8wc&usg=AFQjCNGKT0plhJ7ix67WH5-_1RtC02WoEw)

Answer (score 2):

Lift the door straight up and pull the bottom of the door out first.  They're *designed* not to allow the top of the door to fall out of the track.

Comment: No go.  There is only about 1/8" clearance between the top of the door and the top jamb.  The bottom edge of the door is about 1/2"+ into the track.  The only way I can lift the door up, and have the bottom edge clear the bottom jamb, is if I can lower it so that I can create some slack space at the top.  Make sense?  Stumped.

Comment: Does the amount of clearance change if the door is slid fully open or nearly closed?  Our sliding windows have more clearance for removing them when they're fully opened, but don't lift up much at all when they're nearly closed.  It seems like there's a pocket of space at the open side to allow for easier removal, and less space when they're closed to prevent miscreants simply lifting the windows out.  I would guess that sliding doors might have a similar way of working.